# Using Bundler with RVM

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am just trying to learn Rspec. For that, I had to make a VM with ubuntu linux 14.10. I installed RVM and made 1.9.3 my default. Now, I am trying to install the following gems using the gem - Bundler. I could install each gem using the `gem install` command too. But, I want to use Bundler instead because its well organized.

**Q1** - Will all the installations made via Bundler go through RVM or will they be bypassed ?
If yes, then I'll have to do it manually.

**Here is my file named Gemlock -**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# gem 'ruby','1.8.7'
gem 'rubygems', '1.3.7'
gem 'rspec', '2.0.0'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0'
gem 'cucumber', '0.9.2'
gem 'cucumber-rails', '0.3.2'
gem 'database_cleaner', '0.5.2'
gem 'webrat', '0.7.2'
gem 'selenium-client', '1.2.18'
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
```

**Here is the output of various runs of Bundle install -**

```
john@ubuntu:~/Code/Rspec$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'rubygems (= 1.3.7) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
john@ubuntu:~/Code/Rspec$ bundle install --full-index
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'rubygems (= 1.3.7) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
john@ubuntu:~/Code/Rspec$ bundle install --full-index
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'rubygems (= 1.3.7) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
john@ubuntu:~/Code/Rspec$
```

I saw some posts on Stack overflow which told me to use http instead of https in the gemsource. Failed ! I also tried `bundle install --full-index`. Failed.

**Q2 -** What is the meaning of this error - There is no rubygems 1.3.7 on this system ? That is why I am trying to install it !

Please help me to fix this problem.

When I try to install rubygems 1.3.7 manually, I get -

```
john@ubuntu:~/Code/Rspec$ gem install rubygems -v 1.3.7
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems' (= 1.3.7) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: ruby_gem, rubydeps, ruby-rets, rubyless, rubyjams
```

**UPDATE:**

I commented the rubygems line in my bundler code and got the error -

```
john@ubuntu:~/Code/Rspec$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.7.9)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
john@ubuntu:~/Code/Rspec$
```

Comment: Also I would recommend using the latest version of Ruby unless you have a specific reason to stay with 1.9?

Comment: @Doon - My book uses ruby 1.8.3 (but also allows 1.9.7) for all the Rspec examples. That is why I want to stick to pre 2.0 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `gem 'rubygems'` line from the Gemfile. There is no need for that.

Comment: Please tell me why is there no need for that. My book tells me to use it.

Comment: Which book is that? In the `Gemfile` you specify the gems you use. The ruby and rubygems should be available in the environment. Check the bundler [documentation](http://bundler.io/), I see no example adding the rubygems gem. Afaik there is no `rubygems` gem. Rubygems is standard installed automatically when installing a ruby, and can be updated/installed seperately if you want, but not of course not as a gem. How could you install a gem that will allow to install gems. Chicken and egg problem :) Documentation on installing rubygems: https://rubygems.org/pages/download

Comment: Book="The Rspec Book", Pragmatic publishers. Very old.  I want a book and not online tutorials. This is the only beginner book I could find. Btw, removing gem 'rubygems' did not help and caused a new error.

Comment: At that time bundler did not even exist, and you had to install all gems manually. But afaik even then, when you installed ruby, you automatically got a version of rubygems. Did you try to remove the line? I checked my copy of the book, and there is no mention of a Gemfile (of course).

Comment: So I am looking at an online copy of `The Rspec Book` at http://zepho.com/rails/books/the-rspec-book.pdf ; In the preface, it does list `ruby`, `rubygems`, `rspec`, etc. but that IS NOT a Gemfile. The first time a real Gemfile shows up is in section 19.2

Comment: In the footnote on page 30, it says `We assume that you already have a basic working knowledge of Ruby and Rubygems.
If you don’t, we can recommend 'Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmers’ Guide to learn about Ruby'`. You should do that ;-)

Comment: @PrakashMurthy - Yes, I think I know the bare bones basics - code academy Ruby free tutorials. I am trying to see where I can go with that.